# Lumen / Laravel Auth middleware "ReflectionException in Container.php"

Tags: php, lumen

I am following the lumen docs to use the auth middleware

Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php is untouched and looks like

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if ($request->input('api_token')) {
                return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
            }
        });
```

If i dump out the User, I can see it is finding the user given a correct api token. If i return the User i get the following error

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 576: Class Request does not
>   exist

The function in Container.php is again, untouched and looks like this

```
protected function addDependencyForCallParameter(ReflectionParameter $parameter, array &$parameters, &$dependencies)
{
    if (array_key_exists($parameter->name, $parameters)) {
        $dependencies[] = $parameters[$parameter->name];

        unset($parameters[$parameter->name]);
    } elseif ($parameter->getClass()) {
        $dependencies[] = $this->make($parameter->getClass()->name);
    } elseif ($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
        $dependencies[] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
    }
}
```

Line 576 is

```
} elseif ($parameter->getClass()) {
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to where the Request class needs to be included/used? Adding

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request
```

To Container.php has no affect.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you return the `User`?

Comment: return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();